# Why does my chihuahua still pee in house after I take him out?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I take my dogs out 10+ times a day because they are small dogs with small bladders. My male chihuahua (he's 5) is potty trained but it seems like when he's done doing his business outside he will still pee in the house. Its in the same spot every time.

My female chihuahua is almost 3 and she doesn't do it at all. Is there a way I can stop this without spending a lot of money?

Comment: Are you disciplining the dog in anyway after they do this?  Or just letting them slide by?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, all you need to do is clean the area really well with a urine remover or anything you've got at home--just make sure it's strong enough to remove the chihuahua's pee scent from the spot. And start telling the dog "No" whenever it tries to do it there. And take the dog outside and encourage it to pee there. Also, can it be because you used to train your dog (when it was a puppy) to use that spot as a potty? If so, it's probably going to be harder to train it to stop using the spot. Still, cleaning the area really well will discourage it from using the spot again. Give the dog treats when it goes outside for pee, and either tell it no or ignore it completely when it uses the certain spot.

Take it to the vet before you consider this to be a behavior issue because it may as well be a health one.

If you want the possible reasons:

1. It can be a health issue.
2. It can be a behavior issue based on previous training.
3. It can be due to the dog wanting the place for him, possibly because it has some nice dog stuff.
4. It can be just because it's the dog's routine now.
5. It can be because you go to it every time it pees there and therefore associated the peeing with attention from you.